# how to solve the example on reject or accept the claim

Tags: statistics

A lady stenographer claims that she can take dictation at the rate of 118 words per minute can we reject her claim on the basis of 100 trials in which she demonstrates a mean of 116 words and a S.D. of 15 words.

Comment: you can never reject any probability... you can say, for example,  that there is 99% percent she is incorrect.  hence I think you should provide us with the "Confidence interval" needed to accepet/reject

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you give some more details: what have you tried yourself? What is your confidence interval?

Comment: A 95% CI for her mean rate is roughly $116 \pm 3,$ which contains 118. So the claim believable. If her claim had been 120 wpm, then we could reject $H_0: \mu = 120$ against alternative $H_a: \mu \ne 120,$ according to the usual jargon of statistics. (Another issue here is whether the hypotheses should be  $H_0: \mu \ge 118$ against alternative $H_a: \mu < 118.$) You need to give more context for us to give a precise answer to what is bothering you. Hence, the comment by @Hrodelbert.